# Jquery how to give direction using show effect for multiple divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with some jQuery code, I'm trying to show some fields in a form, but they have to appear only if the user clicks on Yes and hides when he clicks No. This works but when it shows the fields, it mounts them one on top of each other. I'm trying to give it direction, but is not working. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div { background:#def3ca; margin:3px; width:80px;
display:none; float:left; text-align:center; }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<label> Do you want to create a new entry?  </label>
<button id="showr" type="button" >YES</button>
<button id="hidr" type="button" >NO</button>
<br/>

<div class="mydiv">
 <label> Field #1 
 <span class="small">Describe your field</span>
 </label>
 <textarea  rows="10" cols="40" name="" id=""  ></textarea>
</div>

<div class="mydiv">
 <label> Field #2
 <span class="small">Describe your field</span>
 </label>
 <textarea  rows="10" cols="40" name="" id=""  ></textarea>
</div>


<script>
$("#showr").click(function () {
$("div").first().show("fast", function showNext() {
$(this).next("div").show("fast", showNext);
});
});

$("#hidr").click(function () {
$("div").hide(1000);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[relevant jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/RUyxD/)

If somebody has an idea please let me know, thanks

Comment: [relevant fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/RUyxD/)

Comment: Define direction. Your current request is ambiguous

Comment: I want to show every field from the top to the bottom, instead of next to each other, Jsfiddle is not showing the right view but thanks anyway!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/RUyxD/3/)

To get your desired result including centering, use the following CSS:

```
.mydiv {
    background:#def3ca;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:400px;
    text-align:left;
    clear:both;
    display: none;
}
.mytext {
    text-align:center;
}
.wrapper {
    display:block;
}
```

With the following markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <label>Do you want to create a new entry?</label>
    <button id="showr" type="button">YES</button>
    <button id="hidr" type="button">NO</button>
    <br/>
    <div class="mydiv">
        <label>Field #1 <span class="small">Describe your field</span>

        </label>
        <div class="mytext">
            <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="" class="txtField" id=""></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mydiv">
        <label>Field #2 <span class="small">Describe your field</span>

        </label>
        <div class="mytext">
            <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="" class="txtField" id=""></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice I added a wrapper around everything and set `display: block` then in your margin for `.mydiv` I set it to `0 auto`. This allows for centering.

I also worked on your jQuery to improve it a little bit.

```
$("#showr").click(function () {
    $(".mydiv").show("fast");
});

$("#hidr").click(function () {
    $(".mydiv").hide(1000);
});
```

Comment: Hi ChristopherW, thanks for your help, but let me ask you something, when I click on Yes it does a weird jump from left to center, and when I click No it does appear all the way on the left, also theres anyway to have the fields center but the text align to the left?

Comment: Hey i have a quick question, how can I push the window to the bottom when I make a click in Yes?

Comment: @cyberjas2001, your best bet is to write a new question

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your style:

```
.mydiv{ clear:both;}
```

What do you mean by direction?

Comment: Thanks it worked! but now my divs are position on the left, how can I centered them?